# Why make cheese if milk is already food?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In Dwarf Fortress, milk is already a food item, and if I am not mistaken, you get one cheese for every one milk.  So would the only benefit of cheese be that it is just one more ingredient for making meals?  Do dwarves, even without a preference for cheese, generally like cheese better or get more out of it?

Are there any other advantages? (besides cheese loving dwarfs making engravings of cheese)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Milk rots. I'm fairly sure cheese doesn't - or at least does so at a much slower rate.

ETA: Apparently, it does rot, but cheese is ten times as valuable as the milk it was made from - and turning milk into cheese frees up the jug you were using.

... And, of course, is an extra task, meaning extra job experience.

Comment: Cheese **does** rot. There is no real difference, aside from individual dwarf preferences.

Comment: There is nothing in dwarf fortress to support rotting at different speeds. It either `[ROTS]` or it doesn't. Cheese is, however, 10 times more valuable than the raw milk.

Answer (score 5):

I think cheese is worth more, as it can have quality.

Comment: Are you able to confirm this? If you're not sure, you should post this as a comment, not an answer, until you can confirm it.

Comment: @Wipqozn cheese is worth more, but it can't have quality. It does have 10x the value of the milk, however.

Answer (score 2):

And the most important reason: dwarves don't consider milk drinkable. Only booze (and water if injured) is drinkable. Cheese, on the other hand is not only eatable for your dwarves, it is also a solid food which means you can increase its value even more by cooking it into meals with much less trouble than liquid foods.